# SQL query for all sent and received chat

Tags: mysql

sql query to get all sent and received chat and get the last message sent.
Currently I have my office in this way. but does not return messages I sent until the receiver responds.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    chat.`from`,
    chat.`to`,
    chat.`message`,
    chat.`sent`,
    usuarios.`usuario`,
    usuarios.`avatar`
FROM
    chat,
    usuarios
WHERE
    (chat.`to` = 'user')
AND chat.`from` = usuarios.usuario
GROUP BY
    chat.`from`
ORDER BY
    chat.sent,
    chat.message ASC
```

My database look likes

```
| id      | int(10) unsigned
| from    | varchar(255)     
| to      | varchar(255)                  
| message | text                            
| sent    | datetime                       
| recd    | int(10) unsigned
```

Comment: What you described that you want to do, and what you actually doing is not even a like.. please explain better what you want to achieve

Comment: Excuse my English.
In the query I need to read the messages sent to and received from the same user, currently show the query can only see the messages received by the user

Comment: What I need is that the facebook chat where another user appears to resemble the last message sent

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are missing the second condition

```
(SELECT DISTINCT
 chat.`from`,
 chat.`to`,
 chat.`message`,
 chat.`sent`,
 usuarios.`usuario`,
 usuarios.`avatar`
FROM
 chat,
 usuarios
WHERE
 chat.`to` = 'user'  AND chat.`from` = usuarios.usuario

GROUP BY
  chat.`from`
ORDER BY
 chat.sent,
 chat.message ASC)

UNION

(SELECT DISTINCT
 chat.`from`,
 chat.`to`,
 chat.`message`,
 chat.`sent`,
 usuarios.`usuario`,
 usuarios.`avatar`
FROM
 chat,
 usuarios
WHERE
 chat.`from` = 'user'  AND chat.`to` = usuarios.usuario

GROUP BY
  chat.`from`
ORDER BY
 chat.sent,
 chat.message ASC)
```

Comment: I have tried this way but does not return a result in case you have sent the message

Comment: @gamau6 can you tell me the need of usuarios table and please tell me about its columns description especially usuario

Comment: The need for users to learn table is user belongs to each message and get the avatar

Comment: @gamau6 you mean usuarios table contain all the users with username or user_id represented by usuario column---Correct?

Answer (score 0):

can update your query to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    chat.`from`,
    chat.`to`,
    chat.`message`,
    chat.`sent`,
    u1.`avatar`,
    u2.`avatar`
FROM
    chat 
    inner join usuarios as u1 on chat.`from` = u1.usuario
    inner join usuarios as u2 on chat.`to` = u2.usuario
WHERE
    chat.`to` = 'user'
AND chat.`from` = 'user'
GROUP BY
    chat.`from`
ORDER BY
    chat.sent,
    chat.message ASC
```

Comment: returns only 1 result